# replace SherlockFragment with another one

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am using Jake Wharton's TabPageIndicator with ViewPager. Each tab is a fragment that extends from SherlockFragment. In one fragment, on item click, I would like to replace a current fragment with another WITHIN THE SAME TAB. Visually, the current fragment disappears, no exception is thrown, but I get an empty space where the new fragment should be.
Code I am using to replace the fragment is:

```
 SherlockFragment frag = new AboutFragment();
 getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
 .beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
 .replace(R.id.pager_content, frag, "dialogAbout")
 .hide(this)
 .addToBackStack(null)
 .commit();
```

What is the correct way to replace this?

My main_activity xml is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="#000000" />
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/pager_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
     </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>   
</LinearLayout>
```

and in my MainActivity I have set an adapter to viewPager. Adapter extends from FragmentPagerAdapter and looks like follows:

```
private class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

     public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        index = position % CONTENT.length;  
        switch (index) {
        case FRAG_TAG_DEPOSIT:
            return new DepositFragment();
        case FRAG_TAG_HISTORY:
            return new HistoryFragment();
        case FRAG_TAG_LOCATIONS:
            return new LocationsFragment();
        case FRAG_TAG_SETTINGS:
            return new SettingsFragment();
        default:
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
       return getString(CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length]).toUpperCase();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return CONTENT.length;
    }
 }
```

What I don't understand here is - in which containter is the fragment returned from the adapter placed? I don't specifally notify where to put it, I simply state which fragment should be put at which position. Could this be the reason replacement fails?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ViewPager to load your fragments, you don't need to change the fragment manually. Just set the fragment that you want to switch to using the `setCurrentItem` like this where `num` is the  index of the fragment that you want to switch to.

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(num);
```

Comment: But I want to switch fragment in the same tab. I want to stay on the same item, ie. TabIndicator shouldn't be moved

Comment: I think the best way to do that would be to have a `FrameLayout` in your Fragment that you are loading in the tab and then initially load the original Fragment in that. When you want to change Fragment, `remove`/`detach` the fragment from that `FrameLayout` and `add`/`attach` another Fragment there. You should not be manually removing/adding fragments that ViewPager is managing.